# Receive file with servicestack from multipart/form-data

Tags: c#, reactjs, servicestack, form-data

I'm submitting a form as a multipart/form-data from a react app to .net backend. I use FormData on react to post data using axios. On the serverside I'm using servicestack to process the data, text inputs I managed to figure out but the file input I don't know how to receive.

**This is how I submit my form from react**

```
handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = document.getElementById("imageForm"); // You need to use standard javascript object here
        var formData = new FormData(form);

        axios.post('http://myurls.com', formData, {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }})
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
        }) 
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

**This is my servicestack C#**

```
    #region PLUGIN
    public class FormSubmit : IPlugin
    {
        public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
        {
            appHost.RegisterService(typeof(FormSubmitService));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region SERVICE
    public class FormSubmitService : ServiceStack.Service
    {
        public object Post(FormSubmitRequest request)
        {
            return request;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region REQUEST
    [Route("/myservice/submitform")]
    public class FormSubmitRequest : IReturn<object>
    {
        public object ImageFile { get; set; }
        public string ImageTitle { get; set; }
        public string ImageDescription { get; set; }

    }
    #endregion
```

I'm very new to C# and I can't pinpoint what the issue is. My guess was the datatype of the ImageFile, I tried setting it to `object`, `string`, `bytes[]` and `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` but that didn't seem to make any difference.

When I'm returning the request I can see my request object which contains `ImageTitle` and `ImageDescription` but no `ImageFile`, not even an empty key

I'm really lost and don't even know where to begin debugging the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the [ServiceStack docs for handling HTTP File Uploads](https://docs.servicestack.net/serialization-deserialization#uploading-files)